# SPARQL how to obtain license info for an ontology of published papers

Tags: sparql

I am trying to find what type of licenses are used in a dataset of thesis papers, there is a URI where you find license information http://creativecommons.org/ns#license I have tried the following:

```
PREFIX cc: <http://creativecommons.org/ns#license> 
SELECT * WHERE {
?c cc:License ?license .
}
```

However, this displays a blank page, I think the logic is wrong, can anyone explain how I might do this? This might be the wrong way of going about things, I'm new to SPARQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the namespace for the prefix `cc` as `http://creativecommons.org/ns#license` and then you use a prefixed name `cc:License`, it expands to `http://creativecommons.org/ns#licenseLicense`, which is a URI that doesn't exist in the [Creative Commons Rights Expression Language](http://creativecommons.org/ns). What you want is the `http://creativecommons.org/ns#license` property. Try using the following SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX cc: <http://creativecommons.org/ns#> 

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?c cc:license ?license .
}
```